# Update API throwing Parameter missing error in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I am trying to learn and write an update API and to start small I am passing a single params in the API and and try to get the response.

the controller :

```
  module Api
     module V1
       class OrderApiController < ApiController
         def order_update
           response = Hash.new
           result = Hash.new
           @order = Order.find(params[:id])
           if @order.update_attributes(order_params)
             result['order_id'] = order.id
             response['result'] = result
             response.merge! ApiStatusList::OK
           else
             response.merge! ApiStatusList::INVALID_REQUEST
           end
           render :json => response
         end

         private

         def order_params
           params.require(:order).permit( :id)
         end
      end
    end
 end
```

the api route in routes.rb is:

```
  match 'mobile/order_update' =>'order_api#order_update'
```

The url link what I give is

```
  http://localhost:3000/api/v1/mobile/order_update?key=docket&id=1
```

However this throws the following error

```
 ActionController::ParameterMissing at /api/v1/mobile/order_update
              param is missing or the value is empty: order
```

I dont know what am I doing wrong. I am new to Rails as well as API generation. Please help

Comment: I am sorry the answer that i provided was wrong, I have rewritten the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the order_params method, in which you're requiring `order`(expecting order to be a nested hash), whereas, you're not nesting it.

An approach you could take is to visit:

`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/mobile/order_update?key=docket&order[id]=1`

Also, I see you're setting `@order` instance variable, but in your control block(`if @order.update_attributes`), you're using a local variable which would give you another error.

I'd recommend you go through the [Hartl Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) as there are a lot of things you'd be able to learn from there

**UPDATE**

Based on the new error mentioned in the comment, I think you should rather be visiting:

`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/mobile/order_update?order[key]=docket&id=1`

This is assuming your orders table has a column `key` based on the params being set

Also, change your order_params to:

```
     private

     def order_params
       params.require(:order).permit( :key) #since you cannot update a primary key, but I guess you want to update the key column
     end
```

Comment: I realized that earlier and tried passing by order[id]=1,                               but now it throws  :  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /api/v1/mobile/order_update
Couldn't find Order with 'id'=   . I checked my console and tried passing existing records, but it still throws the same error.

Comment: Are you sure an order with that `id` exist?

Comment: Yes it does, i even tried passing the last order id i.e. order[id]=87&order[service_id]=8, it still throws the same error

Comment: oh, I see the problem, updating my answer now

Comment: This the error I get   ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /api/v1/mobile/order_update
Couldn't find Order with 'id'=

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116954/discussion-between-mahesh-mesta-and-oreoluwa).

Comment: Now it gives me this json response error
{"status":"INVALID_API_KEY","message":"Your API key is invalid."}
whereas the key is correct . Can we take this to the discussion forum?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used is as follows

In my order_api_controller.rb , I have Changed

```
def order_update
       response = Hash.new
       result = Hash.new
       @order = Order.find(params[:id])
       if @order.update_attributes(order_params)
         result['order_id'] = order.id
         response['result'] = result
         response.merge! ApiStatusList::OK
       else
         response.merge! ApiStatusList::INVALID_REQUEST
       end
       render :json => response
     end
```

and edited it to this

```
     def order_update
        response = Hash.new
        result = Hash.new
        debugger
        @order = Order.find(params[:order][:id]) # passed the order symbol into params
        if @order.update_attributes(order_params)
            result['order_id'] = @order.id # Modified local variable to instance variable as per oreoluwa's suggestion
            response['result'] = result
            response.merge! ApiStatusList::OK

        else
            response.merge! ApiStatusList::INVALID_REQUEST
        end
        render :json => response
    end
```

And used the url as Follows

```
   http://localhost:3000/api/v1/mobile/order_update?key=docket&order[id]=1
```

This seems to do the trick